# Transforming month names to numbers

Tags: vba, excel, integer, userform

I have a userform that askes to which month the data input is applicable. I have used a combibox with jan, feb, mar etc as possible answers.
Now I want to use these answers to refer to a sheet index number Jan is `sheets(2)`, feb = `sheets(3)` etc.
How do I do this?

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
'Empty maandbox1
MultiPage1.Value = 0
Maandbox.Value = ""
With Maandbox
    .AddItem "Jan"
    .AddItem "Feb"
    .AddItem "Mar"
    'etc
End With
'Set Focus on Monthbox
Maandbox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

And then something like:

```
dim ws as worksheet
dim i as integer
i = Monthbox.Value
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i = Monthbox.Listindex + 2`

should do the trick, since the listindex starts at 0.

Comment: this works, thanks for the easy and fast solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MonthName()`. It takes a Long value and it returns its month. Thus, 1 is `January`, 2 is `February` and etc. To get the first three letters of the month use `Left(value, 3)`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = 1 To 12
        Debug.Print MonthName(cnt)
        Debug.Print Left(MonthName(cnt), 3)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

---

In your case:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
i = Monthbox.Value
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Left(MonthName(cnt + 1), 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateValue function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datevalue-function) to return a dummy date and pull the integer month number from there:

```
Dim dt as Date, i as Long
    dt = DateValue(Maandbox.Value & " 1," & Format(Now(),"YYYY"))
    i = Format(dt, "M") + 1
```

I usually just set the date to the first of the month. The Format(Now(),"YYYY") simply turns the current day's date into a year to complete the DateValue function parameters. I have found this method flexible because it creates a date that you can now format however else you need it. For instance, if you need the full month description, you now have the option of doing:

```
RunMonth = Format(dt, "MMMM")
```

since it's been saved in your variable.